# Cannot finde module 'express' (node app with docker)

Tags: node.js, express, docker

I'm a newbie with Docker and I'm trying to start with NodeJS so here is my question..

I have this Dockerfile inside my project:

```
FROM node:argon

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /home/Documents/node-app
WORKDIR /home/Documents/node-app

# Install app dependencies
COPY package.json /home/Documents/node-app
RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . /home/Documents/node-app

EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

When I run a container with `docker run -d -p 49160:8080 node-container` it works fine..

But when I try to map my host project with the container directory (`docker run -p 49160:8080 -v ~/Documentos/nodeApp:/home/Documents/node-app node-cont`) it doesn't work.

The error I get is: `Error: Cannot find module 'express'`

I've tried with other solutions from related questions but nothing seems to work for me (or I know.. I'm just too rookie with this)

Thank you !!

Comment: I had this issue, I did `npm install --save express` and rebuilt: `docker build -t <image name> .` and it worked, hope this helps.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you run your container with **-v** flag, which mean mount a directory from your Docker engine’s host into a container, will overwrite what you do in **/home/Documents/node-app**,such as npm install.

So you cannot see the **node_modules directory** in the container.

> $ docker run -d -P --name web -v /src/webapp:/webapp training/webapp python app.py
>
> This command mounts the host directory, /src/webapp, into the container at /webapp. If the path /webapp already exists inside the container’s image, the /src/webapp mount overlays but does not remove the pre-existing content. Once the mount is removed, the content is accessible again. This is consistent with the expected behavior of the mount command.

[mount a host directory as a data volume](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/#mount-a-host-directory-as-a-data-volume).As what the docs said,the pre-existing content of host directory will not be removed, but no information about what's going on the exist directory of the container.

There is a example to support my opinion.

1. Dockerfile

   `FROM alpine:latest 
   WORKDIR /usr/src/app
   COPY . .`
2. I create a *test.t* file in the same directory of Dockerfile.
3. Proving

   1. Run command `docker build -t test-1 .`
   2. Run command `docker run --name test-c-1 -it test-1 /bin/sh`,then your container will open bash.
   3. Run command `ls -l` in your container bash,it will show test.t file.
   4. Just use the same image.
   5. Run command `docker run --name test-c-2 -v /home:/usr/src/app -it test-1 /bin/sh`. You cannot find the file **test.t** in your **test-c-2** container.

That's all.I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the similar issue.
Upon digging into docker docs I discovered that when you run the command

*docker run -p 49160:8080 -v ~/Documentos/nodeApp:/home/Documents/node-app node-cont*

the directory on your host machine ( left side of the ':' in the -v option argument ) will be mounted on the target directory ( in the container ) ##/home/Documents/node-app##
and since your target directory is working directory and so non-empty, therefore

> "the directory’s existing contents are obscured by the bind mount."

Comment: This is true when using docker for windows, I am not sure how the behaviour of bind mounts is when using MAC or linux.

Answer (score 0):

I faced an alike problem recently. Turns out the problem was my `package-lock.json`, it was outdated in relation to the `package.json` and that was causing my packages not being downloaded while running `npm install`.
I just deleted it and the build went ok.