# Docker Volumes not persisting changes

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-volume

I *think* that this is a two part error, but the back story here is that I am attempting to learn Docker. I wanted to learn it in order to make some tests on the Google Cloud Platform and I've created the image with a Docker file, but the am having issue with the files persisting changes either on my machine or inside the container.

## Dockerfile (in case it's needed)

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
# Use Ubuntu as the base
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y install curl git
# update & updgrade all the apps. Also install cURL and Git (needed for node, apparently?)
RUN curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | bash - 
# download the node 8.x setup (don't know the words on that one) file
RUN apt-get install -y nodejs
# Install NodeJS
RUN mkdir /var/www/ && mkdir /var/www/app/
# create the directory /var/www/ and then, inside of that directory, create the var/www/app/
WORKDIR /var/www/app/
# our work directory is the app directory
VOLUME /var/www/app
ADD . .
# add everything in the current directory on our file system to the work directory in our container
RUN npm install
# node apps need to have their dependencies installed
CMD ["npm", "start"]
#The command used when the docker container is run.
```

Please note that I do know there are a few NodeJS images already in existence -- this is a learning exercise for me, so I'm doing it from scratch. Odds are in the future I will work with one of the pre-built docker images.

**Going through the building I receive no errors.** I do receive a warning, but it's one I see on every container because I am working on a Windows machine emulating a linux machine.

Now, in my job we have a few Dockerfile containers that I use for a reference, and one of the things I looked up was how the file changes I make in my editor are persisted to the files copied into the container. This appeared to be via the `volume` option in the `docker-compose.yml` file. So, I attempted to create one myself. Please note that I have commented the dockerfile as to my understanding of them. If I am wrong, or note entirely correct, please correct me as I'd like to learn this the right way.

## docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
#what docker-compose version are we using? 3.
services:
  #describes the services to be build when this is composed up 
  web:
    # we will have a web service -- in the future I will obviously need to have some form of database
    build: ./
    #where do we build this image from? the Dockerfile in this directory
    image: dockertest_node
    #what image will be named "dockertest_node" on my machine
    container_name: node_test
    #this container (once build), however, will be titled "node_test" to make it easier to work with and run docker exec commands
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/app
      #volumes, as I understand them, are a map from acutal file system -> containerized file system
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
      # we expose port 8080 from my local machine to port 8080 on the container's machine.
```

Here are the two files in this project, as of right now. These are simple things just to start me off.

## index.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.send('hello world, from express!');
});

app.listen(8080, (err)=>{
    if(err) {
        console.error(err);
        return 1;
    }
    console.log('server started');
});
```

## package.json

```
{
  "name": "docker-test",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Testing",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.0.0",
    "bootstrap":"4.0.0-beta",
    "jquery": "^3.0.0",
    "popper.js":"^1.11.0"
  },
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

### Assorted Other info

#### Docker Version (retrieved from docker -v)

> Docker version 17.09.1-ce, build 19e2cf6

I am using Docker for Windows on Windows 10 Pro

Now if I attempt to run `docker-compose up` I get the following error

```
Starting node_test ...
Starting node_test ... done
Attaching to node_test
node_test |
node_test | > docker-test@0.0.0 start /var/www/app
node_test | > node index.js
node_test |
node_test | module.js:538
node_test |     throw err;
node_test |     ^
node_test |
node_test | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
node_test |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:536:15)
node_test |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:466:25)
node_test |     at Module.require (module.js:579:17)
node_test |     at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
node_test |     at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/index.js:1:79)
node_test |     at Module._compile (module.js:635:30)
node_test |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:646:10)
node_test |     at Module.load (module.js:554:32)
node_test |     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:497:12)
node_test |     at Function.Module._load (module.js:489:3)
node_test | npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
node_test | npm ERR! errno 1
node_test | npm ERR! docker-test@0.0.0 start: `node index.js`
node_test | npm ERR! Exit status 1
node_test | npm ERR!
node_test | npm ERR! Failed at the docker-test@0.0.0 start script.
node_test | npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
node_test | npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean to install?
node_test |
node_test | npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
node_test | npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2017-12-25T22_47_55_509Z-debug.log
node_test exited with code 1
```

Which didn't show up before I added in the volume related information in the `.yml` file and the Dockerfile itself. However, I can login to the container using the command `docker exec -p 8080:8080 -it dockertest_node bash`, where I can manually run `npm start` without issue.

But if while I am in the container I do `touch something.txt` the file is created only within the container; vice-versa, none of my changes to the index.js or package.json file make it into the container.

Thanks for pointing out any errors I may have made; I'm genuinely trying to learn how to work with Docker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45413240/6309), make sure your volume that you are mounting in your docker-compose is not overriding completely what you put in your image (with your `ADD .` directive  in your `Dockerfile`)

Also check out a similar exercise [aherve/simple-dockerized-dev-env issue 2](https://github.com/aherve/simple-dockerized-dev-env/issues/2#issuecomment-250934700)

> It's because the `hello` service is losing the node_modules folder. It needs to be added to the `docker-compose.yml` file

```
volumes:
    - .:/var/www/app
    - /app/node_modules
```

Comment: I will look at this more in depth once I get to work, but this may be my issue.

Comment: are you saying that I should just run the `ADD` command for something like the just the package.json file instead?

Comment: @Jhecht What I am saying is that whatever you are `ADD`'ing to `/var/www/app` would be overridden anyway by your docker-compose volumes directive `- ./:/var/www/app`. By adding a named volume `/app/node_modules`, you are making sure to add persistence to that npm folder.

Comment: ah okay, I think I get what you're saying, but let me double check. Initially I am adding the package.json file, and running npm install. This creates the node_modules folder. However, when I do `docker-compose up` my volume definition overwrites (understood as: replaces) the contents of that folder. Am I in the ballpark here?

Comment: @Jhecht Yes, this is a persistence issue.

Comment: okay, so in this case would I want to declare that persistent volume `/app/node_modules` before the `.:/var/www/app` ?

Comment: @Jhecht before or after: those are two different folders.

Comment: Sorry I'm not understanding something. On my local machine, where would `/app/node_modules` map to without the first portion ?

Comment: ah, so I would create that then?

Comment: @Jhecht The syntax `- /app/node_modules` will create or reuse it, ensuring that whatever is written in it will still be there when the next container is started.

Comment: Finally got it working after having to move around some of the Dockerfile commands, marking this answer as the correct one primarily because of your continued assistance during my learning process @VonC, though Ben's answer was helpful as well.

Answer (score 2):

You’re getting this error because the second volume mapping between host and container does override existing data. More information on starting docker containers is available at [this wiki](https://www.aquasec.com/wiki/display/containers/Starting+Docker+Containers+Automatically).   Since you’re running npm install on your Dockerfile, you have to make sure that you `mount /node_modules` as a data volume in your docker-compose.

So to overcome this, you’ll need:

```
VOLUME /var/www/app
ADD . /var/www/app
RUN npm install
```

Then in the docker compose yaml file include this:

```
…
volumes:
    - ./: /var/www/app
    -  /var/www/app/node_modules
```

Comment: I will try this as soon as I can get back to my DOCKER excursion.

Comment: I do want to thank you and @VonC both, but I can't even attempt this as something is wrong with my docker / computer ( I can't tell at the moment because it's running so damned slow)