# Cannot find module "express" - docker-compose nodejs service

Tags: node.js, docker, express, docker-compose

I'm running a small nodejs microservice in docker. When I run the container standalone with `docker run -p 3000:3000 {image-name}` it works fine. However when I attempt to run it from docker-compose, I get the following error:

```
user_1     | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
user_1     | Require stack:
user_1     | - /usr/src/app/src/app.js
user_1     |     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:15)
user_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:667:27)
user_1     |     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
user_1     |     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
user_1     |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/src/app.js:12:17)
user_1     |     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
user_1     |     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
user_1     |     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
user_1     |     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
user_1     |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:60:12) {
user_1     |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
user_1     |   requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/src/app.js' ]
user_1     | }
```

Here is the Dockerfile for the node service I'm trying to run

```
FROM node:12

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package.json /usr/src/app

# Install npm packages
RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app


EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

To add, express is defined as a dependency in the package.json file, it's not that.

Here is the docker-compose.yml (Relevant snippet)

```
    user: 
        build: ./user-service
        ports: 
            - "2008:3000"
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./user-service
              target: /usr/src/app
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        networks: 
            - backend

    redis: 
        image: "redis:latest"
        ports: 
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - backend
```

The reason I bind the volume is because I want to hot reload the application whenever I make a change.

**What I've tried:**

- Rebuilding the image
- opening a shell inside the container to ensure the files are mapped out correctly - they are.
- clearing all my cache and images, and rebuilding everything just to be sure nothing is cached.

Comment: Double-check the dir inside the container the error says: `requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/src/app.js'`. You can notice the double `src/` maybe you have a wrong map folder or something like that.

Comment: thought that at first, but sadly not - It's correctly mapped.

Comment: In this case for debug you must start the container then attach a shell to it and try yourself the commands `npm install`, `npm start` and compare the folder structure between the container and your dev env.

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem recently, and solved it by creating an [anonymous volume](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/) for the `node_modules` folder to prevent it from being overwritten:

```
volumes: 
  - ./node:/usr/src/app
  # Anonymous volume:
  - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

You also need to give permissions to the `node` user to access the volume:

```
RUN chown -R node:node node_modules
```

Comment: do i need to add `./node:/usr/src/app` too?

Answer (score 1):

Bring down all containers

```
docker compose down -v
```

In your docker-compose.yml file map node_volumes directory

```
volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Build and run containers. (Ensure to delete node_modules directory in root of nodejs app in dockerhost)

```
docker compose build --no-cache
docker compose up -d
```

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45413240/8811037 for more details

Answer (score 0):

docker container is not found your `node_modules` directory

So you have to manually run the `npm install` inside of your `docker image`

```
docker-compose run user npm install
```

format: `docker-compose run [image_name] [command]`

command: `npm install`

In your example

```
     user:  //image name
        build: ./user-service
        ports: 
            - "2008:3000"
        volumes:
            - type: bind
              source: ./user-service
              target: /usr/src/app
        working_dir: /usr/src/app
        networks: 
            - backend

    redis: //image name
        image: "redis:latest"
        ports: 
            - "6379:6379"
        networks:
            - backend
```

Answer (score 0):

Bring down all containers, remove persistant volumes if any.

```
docker compose down -v
```

In your docker-compose.yml file map node_volumes directory

```
volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

Build and run containers. (Ensure to delete node_modules directory in root of nodejs app in dockerhost)

```
docker compose build --no-cache
docker compose up -d
```

refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45413240/8811037 for more details