# docker-compose 'npm install' is not installing

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  application:
    container_name: NodeJS
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    depends_on:
      - mongodb
    build:
      context: ./application
      target: node
    restart: unless-stopped
    extra_hosts:
      - "host.docker.internal:host-gateway"
    volumes:
      - ./application:/app
  ...
```

And then, in `./application/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM node:alpine AS node

# install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache git python3 make gcc g++ libc-dev libpng-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache pixman-dev cairo-dev pango-dev jpeg-dev giflib-dev pkgconfig
RUN npm install -g npm@latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Delete node_modules and package-lock.json for a clean install
# RUN rm -rf node_modules
# RUN rm -rf package-lock.json

# RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

And, lastly, my `./application/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./app.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "base-64": "^1.0.0",
    "better-sqlite3": "^8.6.0",
    "blueimp-md5": "^2.19.0",
    "compression": "^1.7.4",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.4",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "express-robots-txt": "^1.0.0",
    "express-subdomain": "^1.0.5",
    "helmet": "^7.0.0",
    "highlight.js": "^11.8.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.3",
    "identicon": "^3.1.1",
    "identicon.js": "^2.3.3",
    "mongoose": "^7.3.0",
    "morgan": "~1.9.1",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.6"
  }
}
```

Clearly in my `Dockerfile`, I have "npm install" being ran. However, my `npm start` (which is simply `node ./app.js`) just gives me a "Error: Cannot find module 'express'". The project is an ExpressJS project. And if we refer to `package.json`, express@4.18.2 should be getting installed.

Any ideas?

Comment: The `volumes:` block hides everything in your image's `/app` directory, including the `node_modules` subdirectory.  Does deleting it help?  [Cannot finde module 'express' (node app with docker)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39419295/cannot-finde-module-express-node-app-with-docker) discusses this a little bit more.

Answer (score 1):

The **COPY . .** command is copying all files from the current directory (including the node_modules directory, if it exists) into the Docker image, and then you are running npm install, which might not be installing the dependencies correctly due to conflicts with the **existing node_modules** directory.

You can **remove the node_modules** folder before running npm install to ensure that your dependencies are installed correctly in the Docker image.

Updated Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:alpine AS node

# install dependencies
RUN apk add --no-cache git python3 make gcc g++ libc-dev libpng-dev
RUN apk add --no-cache pixman-dev cairo-dev pango-dev jpeg-dev giflib-dev pkgconfig
RUN npm install -g npm@latest

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

# Delete node_modules and package-lock.json for a clean install
RUN rm -rf node_modules
RUN rm -rf package-lock.json

# RUN npm install -g node-gyp
RUN npm install

EXPOSE 3000
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

Comment: This is partially correct. It's true that `node_modules/` might be getting overwritten, but in my case, my working directory does not have node_modules included, so that's why I commented out the `rm` command(s). The intended solve was found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30043872/docker-compose-node-modules-not-present-in-a-volume-after-npm-install-succeeds. Maybe I should Google a bit better before asking next time.