# Docker cannot find module 'express'

Tags: node.js, docker, express

I run "docker compose up", and this is the error message:

```
recipeapp-server-1  | Error: Cannot find module 'express'
recipeapp-server-1  | Require stack:
recipeapp-server-1  | - /usr/src/app/index.js
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1142:15)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:983:27)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1230:19)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/index.js:1:17)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1368:14)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1426:10)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1205:32)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1021:12)
recipeapp-server-1  |     at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:142:12) {
recipeapp-server-1  |   code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
recipeapp-server-1  |   requireStack: [ '/usr/src/app/index.js' ]
recipeapp-server-1  | }
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM node

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

RUN num install express

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["node", "index.js"]
```

With and without "RUN npm install express" give the same result.

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  server:
    volumes:
      - /usr/src/app/node_modules
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3001:3000'
  db:
    image: 'postgres'
    ports:
      - '4444:5432'
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: 'postgres'
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 'root'
```

With and without volumes give the same result.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "recipeapp",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.3",
    "pg": "^8.11.3"
  }
}
```

What I have tried:

1. I have tried to add/remove "RUN npm install express" in Dockerfile and add/remove volume in docker-compose.yml.
2. I have removed package-lock.json according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/75195936/14432555.
3. I have add "node_process: container_name: container_node restart: unless-stopped" under server and changed "- /usr/src/app/node_modules" to "- ./node_process:/var/node_process  - /var/node_process/node_modules" according to https://www.reddit.com/r/docker/comments/muqfds/comment/h8xvfng/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3.
4. I have changed "WORKDIR /usr/src/app" to "WORKDIR /usr/app" and "COPY . ." to "COPY ./src ." in Dockerfile, and changed volumes to "volumes: - ./src:/usr/app/" in docker-compose.yml according to https://forums.docker.com/t/dockerized-node-js-app-error-cannot-find-module/74280/2

The result of trying:

1. Nothing works.
2. Still doesn't work.
3. I get the new error: "validating C:\Path\RecipeApp\docker-compose.yml: services.server Additional property node_process is not allowed"
4. Still doesn't work.

What am I expecting:
Work properly without any error.

Comment: Remove volumes from your docker compose file. You want the container to use the locally installed modules in the container, not ones from your system

Comment: This particular construct stores the `node_modules` directory in a Docker anonymous volume, so it will ignore changes to the `package.json` file and additional manual `RUN npm install ...` commands.  Deleting it is right, especially if it's the only volume mount.

Comment: @AdamJenkins I removed volumes and still doesn't work

Comment: @Hin also move the `COPY . .` before `npm install`. You'll be overwriting `node_modules` with whatever you have in your local directory when running `docker compose build`, which is who knows what. Don't forget to rebuild the image.

Comment: @AdamJenkins I did both moving the `COPY . .` before `npm install` and rebuilding the image. It works now, thanks a lot, but I don't know which step solves the problem.

Comment: `RUN num install express` <- You have a typo here. Why didn't the container build crash? Or did it?